# How can solve this :error: package android.support.v7.app does not exist

Tags: java, android-studio

I have written some codes and when I run my app, this appears: error: package android.support.v7.app does not exist
How can I solve this problem ?!

Comment: You have to share more details who this happened and at least a snippet of the error. Maybe the gradle build script as well.

Comment: Hi try to ask your questions in the clearest way possible. It is always helpful to share some relevant code. in this case, you need to share your gradle file.